# Why passing an initializer_list to allocotr::construct to construct a vector doesn't work?

Tags: c++, allocator

I have a problem here: I am again reading C++ primer 5 edition. Now I am at `std::allocator` everything is Ok but I don't know why my code here doesn't copmile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


void print_vec(vector<int> v) {
    for (const auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    //print_vec(5); // fails. vector(size_t) is explicit

    std::allocator<vector<int>> a;
    auto p = a.allocate(10);
    a.construct(p, 5);// works?!

    //a.construct(p + 1, {7, 16, 23, 81, 77, 24, 10}); // doesn't work even vector(initilizer_list) is not explicit
    a.construct(p + 1, vector<int>({7, 16, 23, 81, 77, 24, 10 })); // works

    for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        for (const auto& e : *(p + i))
            std::cout << e << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    a.destroy(p);
    a.destroy(p + 1);
    a.deallocate(p, 10);


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- Why calling `print_vec` passing an integer doesn't compile -because I guess that the constructor of `vector(size_type)` is `explicit` then why calling `a.construct(p, 5);` works? as long as this value `5` is passed in to the constructor of vector to create 5 value-initialized integer elements.
- Second I can call `print_vec` passing in an `initializer_list<int>` (vector(initializer_list) is not explicit ctor) but why this statement doesn't compile: `a.construct(p + 1, {7, 16, 23, 81, 77, 24, 10});`?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe:  `{ stuff }` has no type.  You cant pass something to a template that doesn't have a type.

Comment: You can pass an `initializer_list` to `construct`. `{...}` isn't an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica But why `a.construct(p, 5);` works?

Comment: Because `5` has a type.  It is `int`.  If you tried `a.construct(p, {5});` it would also fail

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica: I've visited the link you marked and saw that I can specify explicitly the element type: `a.construct<vector<int>>(p + 1, { 7, 16, 23, 81, 77, 24, 10 });` but again this doesn't work`

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa That work around wont work because `construct` is a variadic template.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica: Ok thank you. So I have to explicitly pass an initializer list: `a.constrcut(p + 1, std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4});` This works.

Comment: Simply you have to specify the element type for both `vector<int>` followed by `initializer_list`: `a.construct<vector<int>, initializer_list<int>>(p + 1, {7, 16, 23, 81, 77, 24, 10});` This should work because you told to the compiler that the second argument to `construct` is an `initializer_list`.